# Flutter google-service plugin

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-play-services

For using FireBase services in my Flutter app I've done next recommendation:

*In your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually android/app/build.gradle), add the following line to the bottom of the file.*

```
dependencies {
  // ...
}

// ...

// Add the following line to the bottom of the file:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

As a result during compilation I'm getting this messages:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
```

Used  by version of gsm:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

What should I change for exclude this messages, what the reason. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do nothing.
It will (probably) be addressed by the Flutter dev team soon.